# Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1 stuck on boot screen (bricked)

Tags: cyanogenmod, boot-loop, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

This is going to be a long story because my tablet is just having problems left and right.

Firstly, I received this tablet (SCH-i905) as a gift with cyanogen mod already pre-installed. Thus, in attempts to remove it, I tried to do a clean format in the android settings, but that didn't work.

Then I tried the manual restore to factory settings, holding down the volume button + power button. Selected wipe data/factory reset. This didn't work either, cyanogen mod was still installed.

Then I decided to unmount and mount the system and some other things. That's when I can't even start up my Tablet anymore. It is stuck at the load screen Samsung GALAXY Tab 10.1 .

Now I am trying to flash the original hardware to my tablet using Odin, however I cannot find the rom. I also look into [the official samsung page](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I905UKAVZW), and downloaded the EXE for the USB drive, but can't run ADB.

Where do these ROMs exist or what other alternatives do I have?

EDIT: In the advanced menu, if I select show log, I get the following:

Checking for extendedcommand
Skipping execution of extendedcommand, file not found...
Can't partition no vfat: datamedia
can't format unknown volume: /external_sd
can't format unknown volume: /emmc
unknown volume for path [/sd-ext]
can't remove '/sd-ext/dalvik-cache' No such file or directory

EDIT 2 :

I also tried using Odin with PDA_SIGNED_P7105.tar.md5 . Now my device is in an infinite boot loop.

Comment: All I want for xmas is to restore to factory version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one possible way to restore your device after unmounting system and/or bricking it.

And that is to flash (via [Odin](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=581913&d=1304094576)) the original stock firmware in a file named : [PDA_HC31_EG01Ba_AP352081user_CP1033580_LTE20110704_0708.tar](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/239772/PDA_HC31_EG01Ba_AP352081user_CP1033580_LTE20110704_0708.tar)

**Nothing else will work. Only this one file will be able to unbrick this device.**

The procedure is quite easy.

On the device

1. Hold volume up + Power
2. Select Odin mode (right icon)
3. Connect USB to device and computer

On the computer

1. Download and run Odin 1.85 (This is important because diff versions of Odin support diff files)
2. Check off PDA and select the above tar file
3. Click start (3 boxes should be checked, 2 default and PDA)

The Odin software will then transfer the stock firmware to the device and shut off when the transfer is finished. User must boot up the device again. When the device boots up, it will automatically install the firmware. The device is now officially unbricked.

Comment: Part of the problem I had was finding the original firmware because every website provided dead links. However I eventually did find it. I am not sure if I violate any SE rules by posting a link to a file host here, so just send me an email if you need this file / leave a comment here.

Comment: This is a perfect example of a user answering his own question awesomely, with great instructions and everything. Feel free to [edit] the question and put the link up as it could be useful to someone in the future (and it's so hard to find!). And stick around on Android Enthusiasts!